# Convert like America/New_York in MySQL server 2008 R2 server

Tags: sql-server, database, select

13:30:00 Friday April 19, 2013 in America/New_York converts to
09:30:00 Friday April 19, 2013 in America/Anchorage

Convert like this in SQL Server 2008 R2.

using select query.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,

we will convert in java wright from "America/New_York" to  America/Anchorage like way i need a select query to convert EST time to other time zones..please not the time zone cannot be given like MET,GMT and all...

PLEASE NOTE:- All time zones will only be like plain text America/Anchorage

Comment: I have edited the post content & tags to remove references to MySQL. There is no "2008 R2" release of MySQL, so I'm assuming you mean MS SQL Server - a *very* different product.

Comment: - skartee has stated that he's using mysql on 2008 R2.
And it would work: http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql-with-windows-server-2008-r2-failover-clustering/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this function:

CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)

CONVERT_TZ() converts a datetime value dt from the time zone given by from_tz to the time zone given by to_tz and returns the resulting value. Time zones are specified as described in Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”. This function returns NULL if the arguments are invalid.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: we will convert in java wright from "America/New_York" to  America/Anchorage like way i need a select query to convert EST time to other time zones..please not the time zone cannot be given like MET,GMT and all...all time zones will only be like plain text America/Anchorage

Comment: please try to get  me like this conversion in sql query

Comment: I'm still learning so I can only give you a 'high level idea'.

You could try using user-defined variables with an IF statement:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//user-variables.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

something like

IF(somequery=America/New_York;@var1='MET';@var1='0')

Convert_tz(somequery,@var1,@var2)

I know that this is not a complete answer but it may give you a good approach.

Comment: I don't think the OP is using MySQL.

Comment: It said he was using mysql. Maybe he's using mysql on a Windows 2008 R2 - who knows? My guess here is that we will never know ;)

Comment: I want to do it like this CONVERT_TZ(TZ (America/Anchorage),from_tz(06.00 AM),to_tz(03.00 AM))---> like this i need a direct translation from one time to the other using time zone name....Yannis u r wright i am using mysql on Windows 2008 R2 machine only is there issues with my machine??????

Comment: @skartee as I stated I'm not a pro at mysql so YOU should learn it yourself with the links I provided above so that you can solve YOUR problems ;-)